# Passing a struct as a parameter in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

The following code works fine under Modelsim when the unused localparam is removed. It produces the error below if it is left in. If it is possible to use a struct to pass parameters to a module, what am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
typedef bit [7:0] myarr[2];
typedef struct { int a; myarr bytes; } mystruct;

module printer #(mystruct ms)();

  // works fine if this is removed
  localparam myarr extracted = ms.bytes;

  initial
    $display("Got %d and %p", ms.a, ms.bytes);

endmodule 

parameter mystruct ms = '{ a:123, bytes:'{5, 6}};   

module top;
  printer #(.ms(ms)) DUT ();
endmodule
```

Here is the error. Compilation using vlog -sv -sv12compat produces no errors or warnings.

```
 $ vsim -c -do "run -all; quit" top
 Model Technology ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition vlog 10.5c Compiler 2017.01 Jan 23 2017
 (.......)
 # ** Error: (vsim-8348) An override for an untyped parameter ('#dummyparam#0') must be integral or real.
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a tool bug as `localparam int extracted = ms.a;` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are assigning a whole unpacked array in one statement, which is not allowed.  Try changing the myarr typedef to a packed array instead.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to use a packed array. I didn't need to pack the whole struct.

I would happily upvote/accept someone else's answer if one appears. In particular, it would be helpful to confirm whether this is really a bug in Modelsim, or just an instance of a correct compilation error that could be made more helpful by including the location and parameter name.